# MKMapView addAnnotation crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, exc-bad-access

Hello I am seeing this weird issue, i am populating my own custom annotation to mkmapview in a for loop, after running the for loop for 54 times that is on 55th times when i do mkmapview addannotation on that line it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS here are code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
[mkMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mkMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mkMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[mkMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = currentLocation.latitude;
region.center.longitude = currentLocation.longitude;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.03;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.03;
region.span = span;
[mkMapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE]; 
[mkMapView setDelegate:self];


int i =0;
for(MyObject* myObject in myObjectArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    if(i == 55){
        NSLog(@"%@", myObject);
    }
    i++;
    NSString *maintitle = myObject.name;
    NSString *subtitle = myObject.address;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = { [myObject.latitude doubleValue], [myObject.longitude doubleValue] };
    Annotation *pinAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:newCoordinate title:maintitle subtitle:subtitle image:NULL];
    [mkMapView addAnnotation: pinAnnotation];
    [pinAnnotation release];
}
}

 - (void)dealloc {
mkMapView.delegate = nil;
[mkMapView release];
mkMapView = nil;
[myObjectArray release];
myObjectArray = nil;
[super dealloc];
 }
```

Here is the code for Annotation.h

```
 @interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{
 CLLocationCoordinate2D    coordinate;
 NSString * title;
 NSString * subtitle;
 UIImage * image;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D    coordinate;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;

 - (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate title:(NSString*) title subtitle:(NSString*) subtitle image:(UIImage*) image;

@end
```

Here is the code for Annotation.m

```
 - (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString*) title subtitle: (NSString*) subtitle image:(UIImage*) image{
self = [super init];
if(self){
self.coordinate = coordinate;
self.title = title;
self.subtitle = subtitle;
self.image = image;
}

return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
[title release];
[subtitle release];
[image release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

here are the stacktrace

0 MYAPP 0x00099c6a +[TFCrashHandler backtrace] + 46

1 MYAPP 0x0009a007 TFSignalHandler + 45

2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x9455345b _sigtramp + 43

3 ??? 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295

4 MapKit 0x015f5124 -[MKQuadTrie contains:] + 40

5 MapKit 0x0156363c -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:] + 356

6 MapKit 0x01538807 -[MKMapView addAnnotation:] + 115

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that all annotations you're trying to add has sane coordinates, as this is a common source of crashes when adding them to an MKMapView.

Latitudes should be between -90 and 90 and longitudes should be between -180 and 180.

Comment: What mean by same coordinates? Since I am also facing same issue, app is crashing after adding annotation.

Comment: @NuzhatZari What I meant is that the coordinates should be sane, not same. That is, not have values outside of lat +-90 and long +-180.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked coordinates are proper. But still facing problem. This is something related to annotation. Because when I remove annotation map is not crashing.

Comment: You can use `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()` for the checking.